# My string is output as a bunch of nonsense

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function prototypes */
void wordLength ( char *word );
void wordConcat ( char *wordC1, char *wordC2);


int main (void)
{

    int choice;
    char word [20];
    char wordC1 [20];
    char wordC2 [20];


    printf( "Choose a function by enterting the corresponding number: \n"
        "1) Determine if words are identical\n"
        "2) Count number of words in sentence provided\n"
        "3) Enter two strings to be strung together\n"
        "4) Quit program\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &choice );
    flushall();

    while (choice >= 1 && choice < 4) 

{

        /* if statements for appropriate user prompt and calls function */
        if (choice == 1) 
        {
            /* gather user input */
        printf( "\nYou have chosen to determine word length.\n"
                "Please enter the word:\t");
            gets( word );

            /* call function to output string as well as the string length */
            wordLength( word );


        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            printf( "\nYou have chosen to concatenate 2 words with a % symbol in between them.\n"
                "Please enter word 1:\t");

            gets( wordC1 );

            printf("Please enter word 2:\t");

            gets( wordC2 );                     

            /* call function to output string as well as the string length */
            wordLength( word );
    }
}
}
void wordLength( char *word )

{
    int length;

    printf( "\nThe string entered is:  %s\n\n", word);

    length = strlen (word);

    printf("The string length is: %d\n", length);

    return;
}

void wordConcat(char *wordC1, char *wordC2)

{
    char symbol = "\ 25";
    char result;
    printf( "\nThe first word entered is:  %s\n", wordC1);
    printf( "\nThe second word entered is:  %s\n", wordC2);

    result = strcat( wordC1, symbol, wordC2);

    printf("Output: %s\n", result);

    return;
}
```

Whenever I enter 2 words for the wordConcat function of my program the string output is a bunch of nonsense :( All of my pointers appear to be pointing at the right places. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: you just asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336808/how-do-you-concatonate-strings-in-c

Comment: I don't see a call to wordConcat anywhere in your code...

Comment: Yes :( but it isn't working everything appears correct but the output is "╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠☻"

Comment: void functions don't need a return on the end.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `char symbol = "\ 25";`

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `result = strcat( wordC1, symbol, wordC2);`

Answer (score 1):

`choice == 2` code is calling `wordLength()` instead of `wordConcat()`, so the `word` variable it passes in is not set.

Comment: Wow, I need to stop copy and pasting... Thanks for fixing my idiotic mistake... And now I get an exception

Comment: Never mind I fixed my own problem for once! Thanks!