# Chose To write a File to a Specific Directory

Tags: c, fopen, c-strings

So I'm trying to create a file and save it to a desired directory.

eg: user-input:

Directory? `c:\user\sample\`

Name? `hello.txt`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
char str[200],str2[200];
FILE * out_file;
fgets(str,sizeof str,out_file);
fgets(str2,sizeof str2,out_file);
out_file = fopen(str+str2,"w");
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings with the `+` operator in C. Use `strcat` or any other appropriate function for this purpose.

Comment: As, @FUZxxl said, you will have to use `strcat` to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Read this [How to concatenate 2 strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-to-concatenate-2-strings-in-c)

Comment: You should have at least reported which kind of error you had, i.e. at compile time (which error?) or runtime (which wrong behaviour?)

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

- You'll have to use [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) to concatenate the strings.
- Here you are reading from `out_file` before opening it.

  ```
  fgets(str,sizeof str,out_file);
  fgets(str2,sizeof str2,out_file);
  ```

A quick example (no error checking done):

```
char str[200], str2[200];
char fname[400];
FILE *out_file;

printf("\nEnter path: ");
scanf("%199s", str);  
printf("\nEnter filename: ");
scanf("%199s", str2);

strcpy(fname, str);
strcat(fname, str2);

out_file = fopen(fname, "w");
```

Or, a shorter way:

```
char str[400],str2[200];
FILE * out_file;

printf("\nEnter path: ");
scanf("%199s", str);  
printf("\nEnter filename: ");
scanf("%199s", str2);

strcat(str, str2);

out_file = fopen(str, "r");
```

Comment: Never use `gets`. Use `fgets`.

Comment: `gets` is very much dangerous. Check this out: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: @AshishAhuja - Yes, but wanted to keep the sample short (newlines etc.) - Used `scanf()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to concatenate 2 strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-to-concatenate-2-strings-in-c).

Also, you should use [`strcat`](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcat.php).

Check out [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcat.php) tutorial.

An example in this is:

```
/* Example using strcat by TechOnTheNet.com */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   /* Define a temporary variable */
   char example[100];

   /* Copy the first string into the variable */
   strcpy(example, "TechOnTheNet.com ");

   /* Concatenate the following two strings to the end of the first one */
   strcat(example, "is over 10 ");
   strcat(example, "years old.");

   /* Display the concatenated strings */
   printf("%s\n", example);

   return 0;
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
char file_name[200 + 200];
file_name [0] = '\0'                    // To make sure that it's a valid string.

strcpy (file_name, str);                // Concatenate `str` and `file_name`
strcat(file_name, str2);                // Concatenate `str2` and `file_name`

out_file = fopen(file_name, "w");       // Open the file.
```

Also, thanks to 'laerne' for pointing out some mistakes.

Comment: You should initialize `file_name[0] = '\0'` to make sure it's a valid empty string.  Or copy the first string entirely with `strcpy`.

Comment: @Lærne, alright I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot concatenate strings like this in C!** *

You'd better use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
char fname[200+200];

strcat(fname, str);
strcat(fname, str2);

out_file = fopen(fname, "w");
```

<sub>* Although you are allowed to add pointers. In your case it doesn't do what you expect.</sub>