# How to add two strings?

Tags: c, c-strings, string-concatenation

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char a[] = "My name is";
    char b[] = "kamran";

    printf("%s %s", a+b);

    return(0);

}
```

I was trying to add two strings but getting error of **"Invalid operands to binary"**

Comment: It looks like you've omitted the tail of the error message.  The whole message is probably something like "Invalid operands to binary +".

Comment: You need not add two arrays to print them one after the other. See the answer. If you really want to add them to a third string, the easiest way would be by using functions declared in <string.h> header. (-:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-to-concatenate-2-strings-in-c

Comment: Add two strings? Do you mean concatenate? You should use `strcat()` then.

Comment: @Haris, the OP cannot use `strcat()` to concatenate his strings (as currently written) because there is insufficient space in array `a`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, True. I just wanted to get to know what he exactly wants. I would have given the details after that.

Comment: That's not c++, you cant use '+' to concatenate (add) two strings! You must use strcat()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this expression

```
a+b
```

the array designators are implicitly converted to pointers to the first characters of the strings. So in fact you are trying to add two pointers of type `char *`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

However `operator +` is not defined for pointers in C and C++.

If you indeed want to add two strings then the result of the operation will be a third string that contains the first two strings.

There are two approaches. Either you declare a third character array large enough to contain the first two strings. Or you need to allocate dynamically memory for the resulted string.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char a[] = "My name is";
    char b[] = "kamran";
    char c[sizeof( a ) + sizeof( b )];

    strcpy( c, a );
    strcat( c, " " );
    strcat( c, b );

    puts( c );

    char *d = malloc( sizeof( a ) + sizeof( b ) );

    if (  d )
    { 
        strcpy( d, a );
        strcat( d, " " );
        strcat( d, b );

        puts( d );
    }

    free( d );
}
```

The program output is

```
My name is kamran
My name is kamran
```

Comment: A well detailed answer that one i was looking for specially that is what i was wanted to with my program, Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can concatenate `b` to `a` like this:

```
char a[18] = "My name is "; // a needs to be big enough
char b[] = "kamran";

strcat(a, b);

printf("%s", a);
```

To use `strcat()` you need to include `string.h`.

Comment: Please, don't forget `#include <string.h>`

Comment: That's C++, not C