# Assigning value to char array in C doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays

I want to assign a value to my `char *` like that:

```
char *text;
struct node *ptr = head;

//start from the beginning
while(ptr != NULL)
{        
   text = ptr->key + ";" + ptr->data + ";\n";
   ptr = ptr->next;
   fprinft(f, text);
}
```

The key value is a `char[]` and the data value an `int`.

I get the following error:

> Error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’) text = ptr->key + ";" + ptr->data + ";\n";

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Comment: `strcat` is your friend.

Comment: Your compiler will certainly have told you something useful about this snippet.

Comment: Error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
       text = ptr->key + ";" + ptr->data + ";\n";

Comment: This is not the syntax for constructing a concatenation of four strings. Take a look at `strcat`, or implement your own.'

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate 2 strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-to-concatenate-2-strings-in-c)

Comment: I have a string and an `int` value

Comment: @mafioso Then use itoa (or implement it yourself, since n + '0' = 'n', n is any alphabet) and then use strcat()

Comment: You really need a better book on `c`.  Your history shows no gained understanding of the subject.

Comment: Read the man page for `fprintf`. You don't need the `text` variable, or `strcat`. You just have to call `fprintf` with the correct format string, and arguments.

Comment: thanks @user3386109, worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the concatenation of `ptr->key`, `";"`, `ptr->data`, `";\n"` does not need to exist after the loop, just print it to the file.  [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986426/assigning-value-to-char-array-in-c-doesnt-work/39987512#comment67252578_39986426)

```
// Not needed
// char *text;

struct node *ptr = head;

while(ptr != NULL) {
   //           v--v----- printf specifiers for a pointer to a string and int 
   fprinft(f, "%s;%d;\n", ptr->key, ptr->data);
   ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to malloc() it. This is because strings in c are stored in memory as arrays of chars but if you don't malloc() it and initialize a string as

```
char* string = "this is a string";
```

it will be stored in read only memory.

What you can do is either malloc() it or store it as an array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

First you would need to allocate memory for your `*text`, and then use strcat function for adding these strings together...

```
#include <string.h>
void function(...) {
  char* text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // for 99 chars + NULL 
  text[0] == 0;
  struct node* ptr = head;

  //start from the beginning
   while(ptr != NULL)
   {
     if(text[0] == 0)  //you cant strcat empty string, only existing one
       strcpy(text, ptr->key);
     else
       strcat(text, ptr->key);
     strcat(text, ";");
     strcat(text, ptr->data);
     strcat(text, ";\n");
     ptr = ptr->next;
     fprinft(f, text);
  }
}
```

This code assumes both `ptr->key` and `ptr->data` are char arrays (strings), if they are not, you need to convert them to strings : look into `itoa` function...

Comment: Of course, I was thinking of `itoa`. Small confusion.

Comment: Where did you get the "you cant strcat empty string, only existing one" from?

Comment: I get the following error executing your code: /tmp/ccu6S8bc.o: In function `main':
WriteInFile.c:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `itoa'
WriteInFile.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `fprinft'

Comment: @mafioso Because it's `fprintf` and if `key` is `char*` while `data` is an `int` you only have to write `fprintf(f, "%s;%d;\n", ptr->key, ptr->data);`

Comment: `text[0] == 0; strcat(text, ptr->key);` is just fine.  `text[0] == 0; strncat(text, ptr->key, 100);` is even better.