# Can I change the last 4 letters of a string variable, that is already initialized?

Tags: c

In C, If I have a string assigned to a variable, and I want to change only the last 4 letters in that string for something else, how should I do it? `strcat()`? Something like:

```
int size;
char a[10] = "something";
size = strlen(a) - 4;

strcat(a + size, "1234");
```

Would that work? to get `somet1234` ? or would it just be `something1234` ?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465083/3521116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strncpy` (to prevent an extra terminator from being appended) to overwrite from a given position:

```
strncpy(a + size, "1234", 4);
```

If you really want `strcat`, cut the string manually for `strcat()` to find the starting place to concatenate:

```
a[size] = '\0'; // Cut the string so strcat() know where to start
strcat(a, "1234");
```

Comment: Since `size` is computed relative to the trailing NUL, there is no danger is in overwriting it and `strcpy` would work fine. But I'd use `memcpy`.

Comment: @rici `memcpy` is also a good option but it has nothing better than `strncpy`. I could have added `memcpy`, but that's only a copy of my existing code and a replacement of the function name.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work.  If you used `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()` it would.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string convertto(string abc,string replacewith,int len) 
                     //something,   1234 and     length to replace i-e 4
    {
        int g = strlen(abc);
        int f = g - len;
        j=0;
        char[] temp =new char[g];
        for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
        {
            if (i >= f)
            {
                temp[i] = replaceWith[j];
                  j++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[i] = abc[i];
            }
        }            
        return temp.ToString();
    }
```

// It will return somet....

Comment: Did you not see that the question is tagged C?