# Adding a string to another string

Tags: c, string, function, malloc

Exercise:

> Write a function that returns a CH character string after adding a CH1 string at the end of a CH2 string given as a parameter.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ajout(char ch1[], char ch2[]);

int main() {
    char ch1[] = "hello";
    char ch2[] = "ooo";
    char *ch = ajout(ch1, ch2);
    printf("%s",ch);
    return 0;
}

char *ajout(char ch1[], char ch2[]) {
    char *ch;
    int nb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; ch1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        ch[i] = ch1[i];
        nb++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i; ch2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        ch[nb] = ch2[i];
        nb++;
    }
    return ch;
}
```

The expected result after program execution: `helloooo`

Comment: `char *ch;` has no memory allocated (in the function `ajout`). Try `ch = malloc(1 + strlen(ch1) + strlen(ch2));` And you should add a nul terminator to the concatenated string.

Comment: Try malloc and read up about buffer overflows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: thank you @weathervane that's what i do :` int c = malloc(1 + strlen(ch1) + strlen(ch2));
    char ch[c];
     *ch=ajout(ch1,ch2);` but it's still not woking,what's the wrong with my code ?

Comment: Post any update in the question  (full implementation) so that we can revision it.

Comment: That's become a muddle, sorry. You allocate memory for the new array and assign its pointer to an `int`. Then you define a variable length array, using an address as its length. The two changes I suggested are really rather simple. I spelled out the first and left the second (the nul terminator) for you.

Comment: thank you @alexandervanoostenrijk ,not really i saw the ansewrs but they use strcpy function , in this exercice i should not use another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a string in C is just a pointer to an array of char that is terminated by the first null character. There is no string concatenation operator in C.

Also, in order to create a new array in C - you need to allocate memory for it using `malloc`. However, in the `ajout` function, you don't allocate any memory for `ch`. Solution:

```
const size_t len1 = strlen(ch1); //get ch1 length
const size_t len2 = strlen(ch2); //get ch2 length
char *ch = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); //create ch with size len1+len2+1 (+1 
                                    //for null-terminator)
```

I see you copy each char of `ch1` and `ch2` into `ch` one by one. A better solution would be to  copy `ch1` and `ch2` using `memcpy`. Also, after allocation memory using `malloc`, you need to deallocate the string using `free`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* ajout(const char *ch1, const char *ch2)
{
    //get length of ch1, ch2
    const size_t len1 = strlen(ch1);
    const size_t len2 = strlen(ch2);

    //create new char* array to save the result 
    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); // +1 for the null-terminator
    // in real code you would check for errors in malloc here

    //copy ch1, ch2 to result
    memcpy(result, ch1, len1); 
    memcpy(result + len1, ch2, len2 + 1); // +1 to copy the null-terminator
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char ch1[] = "hello";
    char ch2[] = "ooo";
    char *ch = ajout(ch1,ch2);
    printf("%s",ch);
    free(ch); // deallocate the string
    return 0;
}
```

output:
helloooo

You can read more about `memcpy` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) and about `malloc` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).