# Log an array of bytes without fragmenting heap

Tags: c, stm32, heap-corruption

I am running some code on a STM32 chip which is logging to my uart port.

I am having a hard time finding the proper way to log an array of bytes. I wrote this function:

```
static void LogBytes(uint8_t *data, uint32_t length)
{
    char message[length*6]={};
    static char byteRepresentation[6];

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        sprintf(byteRepresentation, "0x%02X ", data[i] & 0xFF);
        strncat(message, byteRepresentation, 6);
    }

    logger.WriteDebug(LoggingCategorySio, message);
}
```

But when I run this, I eventually get hard faults (which are a pain to troubleshoot, but I suspect it's caused by heap corruption/fragementation).

I think the problem is caused by `strncat` (the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465014/1470327) warns about some problems I might be experiencing). I also read to stay away from malloc / free as much as possible. So I am trying to do as much as I can on the stack.

Am I missing some stupid bug in this code? Or should it be done completely different?

From the comment:

> "there are other, quicker and more efficient alternatives (such as
> strcpy() or memmove()) that could be used instead. Pretty much
> whatever the question of 'what should I use', strncat() is not the
> answer"

Is it indeed better to use strcpy / memmove? Or do they in fact rely more on malloc / free and thus should I avoid that even more?

Comment: Since the length of one token is fixed in this case, it looks better to specify the place to construct the string directly than using funtions like `strcpy` or `memmove`, like `sprintf(message + 6 * i, "0x%02X ", data[i] & 0xFF);` Also note that you have to allocate one more element for the terminating null-character.

Comment: Each loop is creating a `byteRepresentation[]` string length `5` bytes (and terminator) so there should not be any overflow, which would be on the stack not the heap. Perhaps some there is some other cause of heap fragmentation.

Comment: @MikeCAT tried your suggestion, but I guess something else is causing it. I can control the maximum amount of bytes my reading thread takes in. If I reduce it (thus decrease the stack size significantly) the problem seems to be fixed. I will have to dig further. Thx for the better implementation, I'll stick with this anyway.

Comment: Oops, `"0x%02X "` actually produces 5-character strings like `0xAA `, so there actually no need to allocate an extra space. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: Yeah figured that when I copy pasted your suggestion and I was printing 1 byte instead of a whole bunch. I miscounted myself, my initial code caused the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem did end up being from  heap overuse (from `strncat`), then you could try out this implementation that uses the return from `sprintf` to append to the string as your building it.

```
static void LogBytes(uint8_t *data, uint32_t length)
{
    char message[length*6];
    memset(message, 0, length*6);
    size_t message_offset = 0;

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<length; i++)
    {   
        int ret = sprintf(message + message_offset, "0x%02X ", data[i] & 0xFF);
        if (ret > 0){
            message_offset += ret;
        } else {
            //TODO react however you want to sprintf error
            break;
        }   
    }   

    logger.WriteDebug(LoggingCategorySio, message);
}
```

However, there could also be problems from overflowing the stack. If that's the problem, then this variable length array `char message[length*6];` might be the culprit for hardfaulting when printing super large arrays.

Comment: Little things: 1) Nice alterative to `memset(message, 0, length*6);`: `memset(message, 0, sizeof message);`.  2) With `"0x%02X "`, could use `length*5 + 1`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Using your `sprintf` which was suggested by MikeCAT too. The memset doesn't add anything over `char message[size] = {};` right? Anyway, I think your comment on super large arrays is indeed the cause. When I reduce the maximum amount of bytes read each cycle the problem dissappears. I have asserts on stackhighwatermark (freertos). They are all satisfied. I'll dig a bit deeper. But this really helped

Comment: If I may, one side question: does `strncat` or `sprintf` malloc memory under the hoods, and should I be concerned with that (e.g. does it fragment my heap?). I see that a library I use (lwip) mallocs a big deal as well. Since that is meant to run on microcontrollers I am a bit lost on "never use malloc / free".

Comment: @bas `char message[size] = {};` --> "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized".

Comment: `char message[(length*5)+1]={};` this compiles fine though

Comment: About the `memset` line, With gcc 8, I  was getting a compiler error on this line: `char message[(length*5)+1]={};` but if that compiles for you, I like that solution without `memset` better :)