# Having some trouble with string.h library in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I have run this code in C,

```
char *bracket_by_len(char *output, char *word, int length)
{
    if(strlen(word) < 5) {
        output[0] = '<';
        output[1] = '<';

        /*int i = 2;
        while(i != (strlen(word) + 2)) {
            output[i] = word[i - 2];
            i += 1;
        }*/

        strncat(output, word, strlen(word));
        strcat(output, ">>");
return output;
} else {... not using them as 4 letter word for input}

int main()
{
    char word[40], output[40]; // word is not used.
    printf("%s \n.", bracket_by_len(output, "word", 20);
    return 0;
}
```

The actual code is this:[Input code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCgcw.png)
I then wrote

```
return output;
```

I printed this with

```
printf("Based on size, \t %s.\n", output);
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Based on size, <<^S>>.
```

There are some random characters in the beginning. When I replaced the strncat() function by a while loop with manually copying the letters of the word, the input is alright.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two characters are random. There are two different characters being added every time I run the program.

Comment: How is output and word defined?

Comment: You'll need to show us significantly more of your code if you want anyone to diagnose the problem and offer a solution.

Comment: How is `output` declared and initialized? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show the whole code? Why start from `output[1]` and not `output[0]`?

Comment: The word is pre-defined, and I'm not using any input. I did start from output[0] in my program.

Comment: Post the complete code. Not just a little piece. And no image of code. Post it in text.

Comment: `output[2] = 0;` is missing, required to generate a zero-terminated string.  `strcpy(output, "<<");` makes more sense.

Comment: @HansPassant I think '\0' is the way to go, '0' can be interpreted differently depending on the OS

Comment: Aside: Why `strncat(output, word, strlen(word));` instead of simple `strcat(output, word);` or `strncat(output, word, 37);`?

Comment: I wanted to add some characters after word part, so I didn't use strcat directly.

Comment: @SreenadhaSaranga Consider `snprintf(output, 40, "<<%s>>", word);`

Comment: @shrewmouse, "guy is new" is not an excuse. If he's new he should read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Downvotes do reflect the quality or usefulness of the question and are not personal. By the way, it doesn't even cost reputation, since you cannot get lower than 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: PS: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output` hasn't been terminated with a NULL.  Add it after the left chevrons.

```
output[0] = '<';
output[1] = '<';
output[2] = 0;
strncat(output, word, strlen(word));
printf("%s\n", output);
```

If you use `sprintf` in stead you won't have to worry about adding the null that detail.

```
sprintf(output, "<<");
strncat(output, word, strlen(word));
printf("%s\n", output);
```

Comment: I did try that. I wrote output[1] by mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Based on your output, I but that the first char of `word` wasn't been initialized

Comment: No, I passed my command as function(output, "word", 20);

Comment: Loop through `output` and `word` and print each char as an integer `printf("%d\n",output[i])`.  You will be able to find the value of the offending char. ^S is likely a single char.

Comment: When I did the loop, I got perfect output as expected.

Comment: @SreenadhaSaranga, set output[2] to null.  strings are null terminated.

Comment: But I want to add some characters after that. Won't it affect this?

Comment: No.  it will only affect the first three characters. '<' ,'<','\0'  It's the same as your first three lines where you set the chars of `output` directly.