# printing * corresponding to the number of iteration

Tags: c, algorithm

So in C I'm supposed to let the user input an integer n from the interval [5, 25]. And then, for every number from 1 to n, in a new line print that many stars so it would look something like this:

```
*

**

***
```

I tried doing it like this, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int n, i;
    char star = '*';

    do {
        printf("Input an int from [5, 25]");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 5 || n >= 25);


    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        star += '*';
        printf("%c", star);

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow, there's *a lot* of people asking about how to print asterisks here today. Is this from some popular puzzle site or lecture?

Comment: also, what does `+=` for a `char` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `star += '*';` because you declared star as a char, C is strongly typed, a char is a char not a table of char.

You have to use nested loop, like this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int n, i, j;
    char star = '*';

    do
    {
        printf("Input an int from [5, 25]");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 5 || n >= 25);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops

```
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
```

or if you want to use strings:

```
    char str[n + 1];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        str[i] = '*';
        str[i + 1] = 0;
        puts(str);
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aT8brP1ch

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    int n,i,j;
    printf("enter a number between 5 & 25");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
star += '*';
```

is not the correct way to concatenate two strings in C. In order to do this, you can define an array with sufficient space for the string and use the function [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    //initialize "stars" to an empty string
    char stars[20] = {0};

    do {
        printf("Input an int from [5, 25]: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 5 || n >= 25);

    //build the string containing the stars using repeated
    //string concatentation
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        strcat( stars, "*" );
    }

    //print the string
    printf( "%s\n", stars );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Input an int from [5, 25]: 5
*****
```

However, this is highly inefficient and unnecessarily complicated. Instead of first building the string in an array before printing it out all at once, it is usually easier to simply print it one character at a time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    do {
        printf("Input an int from [5, 25]: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 5 || n >= 25);

    //print the stars one character at a time
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        putchar( '*' );
    }

    //end the line
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the same output as the first program.

You now have the solution for printing out a single line. However, your task involves printing out several lines. This will require a nested loop. In accordance with the [community guidelines on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471), I will not provide the full solution at this time, as you should attempt to do this yourself, first.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is an [integral type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) - that is, it represents a number. `'*'` is a [Character Constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant), which actually has the type `int`.

```
char star = '*';
star += '*';
```

In ASCII, this is no different from

```
char star = 42;
star += 42;
```

A [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) is a series of nonzero bytes, followed by a zero byte (the null terminating character, `'\0'`). You cannot build a string by adding two integers together.

To build a string, you must place each byte in a buffer in sequence, and ensure a null terminating byte follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN 5
#define MAX 25

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    do {
        printf("Input an int from [%d, %d): ", MIN, MAX);

        if (1 != scanf("%d", &n)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while (n < MIN || n >= MAX);

    char buffer[MAX + 1] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        buffer[i] = '*';
        buffer[i + 1] = '\0';
        puts(buffer);
    }
}
```

*Aside: never ignore the return value of `scanf`.*

Or you can avoids strings, and just print the characters directly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        putchar('*');

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

String concatenation does not work like that in C, instead use strcat().

Comment: You may want to quote the line of code you are talking about (i.e. `star += '*';`) and provide an example of using `strcat`. In its current state, the short text you wrote would be a good comment, but not a good answer. Note that you have sufficient reputation for writing comments, because you have at least 50 reputation.