# Fille path problems in C

Tags: c, winapi

I'm a noob.
Trying to make a silly c program that changes desktop wallpapers with the pic in its folder. Can't work out how to concatenate the path to the pic with .exe file path.

Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(module, path, MAX_PATH);
    wcscat(path, L"//gwegus/pic.png");
    int retSysCall = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0,(void*)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    printf("%s",path );
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-c

Comment: Your exe name is `argv[0]`, you only need to change your main signature.

Comment: Well, what does that `printf("%s", path);` tell you?

Comment: You need to remove the executable name before appending the image name.

Comment: oh i see that it types the first char in path array

Comment: @pptaszni That's a convention, not a contract. Applying your recommendation makes the code *less* robust.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how do i remove it if str funcs use char type and this has a wchar_t type, even printf doesnt want to work with it

Comment: Yep true, I also gave the link to the answer with couple of tricks to get executable path.

Comment: Your code is using a `wchar_t` string, so you need to use the functions from `<wchar.h>` — which may already be included by `<windows.h>` since the type `wchar_t` is already known.  See [§7.29 Extended multibyte and wide character utilities `<wchar.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29) or the equivalent Microsoft documentation.  The [`wcsrchr()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.4.5.4) function might be relevant, for example.